# how can i get this value of this input id value (this value was loaded from other input value by ID )

Tags: javascript, php, input

THIS IS THE FORM
the value between the input tage is the name* value that coms from the myid from another input that was created with javascript create.element.

my qs is that how can i get the value *name* and into the name.php

```
                <form method="POST" action="name.php">

                    <input type="hidden" name="myname" id="myid" value="000" >name</input>

                    <input type="submit" name="submit" >
                </form>
```

the php only get the value 000

thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`name` won't be sent to `name.php`, only `value` in `<input>` can be sent to the action url.So if you want get `name`, you can add another `<input>` like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="myname" id="myid" value="000">
<input type="text" name="whatever" value="name" readonly>
```

And if you want make it editable, just remove the `readonly`.

Comment: thank you for the answer but didn't work the "name" was printed by javascript id